# SQL select query from comma separated string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table with with column `location` with values

```
row1: sector A, sector B, Sector c
row 2: sector B, sector f, Sector A
row 3: sector f
```

No I am looking for the sql query to search from these rows with comma separated  string say I can search with `Sector A, sector f` in that case row 1 ,row2, row 3 values should print as `Sector A` is in row 1, row2 and `sector f` is in row 3

I am trying something like this but matches the exact string only ...

```
SELECT id , name FROM tb1 "+
" where    Charindex(','+cast(location  as     varchar(8000))+',',',"+loc+",') > 0
```

and loc is sector A,sector f

Comment: You should really normalize your database and get rid of those comma separated values.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen can you give some more clarity..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having "location" column in your main table with comma separated values, what you really should have is a second table. I'm going to call your first table inventory_item and assume here you're trying to track the locations where that inventory is located (since you didn't say what your application does).

So add a table called inventory_item_location with columns:

id, inventory_item_id, location

You would have one row per location in that inventory_item_location table and the inventory_item_id would be the id of your inventory_item table. So then you just query the inventory_item_location table for whatever sector you're looking for. And you know what items are in that locaiton.

Comment: Bonus: Set a unique index on inventory_item_id, location